# Limit the intercept for fit with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, limit, intercept

I have a simple linear fitting function as:

```
f(x) = m*x + b
```

however, the fitting end up having a negative intercept (b<0) which does not have any meaning in my use case. 
I need to restrict the intercept to be only positive numbers. The code that I found

```
fit [b=0:] f(x) "name_of_the_file" u 1:2 via m, b
```

only works for x variable restriction, but not for any other parameter.
How can I limit the intercept to positive numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify your fitting function and replace b by c**2:

```
f(x) = m*x + c**2
fit f(x) "name_of_the_file" u 1:2 via m, c
```

Then you have a nonnegative b = c**2.